# Baofeng UV-9R Chirp Pinout

Tags: baofeng, radio-programming

I'm searching the pinout of the Baofeng UV-9R to programm it with Chirp.

Answer (score 2):

The Pinout is as in the following Picture:

[image: Baofeng UV-9R pinout photo]

I used a cheap USB<->RS232 Adapter with 5V TTL voltage level.
In Chirp I used the UV-82WP Model.